# Why doesn't Interactive Grid process save values set using the Model interface in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

I'm writing a JavaScript function to allow users of an application built using Oracle Application Express 21.1 to paste data from Excel spreadsheets into an Interactive Grid and save the data. Using the APEX JavaScript API I can update the model of the Interactive Grid with the data; the pasted values display correctly and when I subsequently access the model the correct values are returned.

However when the Interactive Grid is saved, those values aren't saved to the underlying database table. What happens is:

- Null columns updated by the JavaScript function remain null
- Columns with existing data and then set by the JavaScript function become null
- Null columns and columns with existing data that are then changed normally by the user are updated correctly
- Columns initially set by the JavaScript function and then changed normally by the user are updated correctly

The grid is a simple Interactive Grid region based on the default EMP table, with a static ID of EmployeeGrid, and saves using the Interactive Grid process that is automatically generated when the grid was created.

I have entered the following code in the **Execute when Page Loads** section:

```
$("#EmployeesGrid_ig").on('paste', onPaste);
```

I have entered the following code in the **Function and Global Variable Declaration** section:

```
function onPaste(e) {
  
  if (!e.originalEvent.clipboardData ||
      !e.originalEvent.clipboardData.items) return;
  let items = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.items;
  let data;
  for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].type == 'text/plain') {
      data = items[i];
      break;
    }
  }
  
  if (!data) return;
  data.getAsString(function(text) {
    // Split the clipboard data into rows.
    text = text.replace(/\r/g, '').trim('\n');
    let rowsOfText = text.split('\n');
    let rows = [];
    
    // Iterate over each row of text and push the trimmed data into rows[]
    rowsOfText.forEach(function(rowOfText) {
      let row = rowOfText.split('\t').map(function(colAsText) {
        return colAsText.trim().replace(/^"(.*)"$/, '$1');
      });

      rows.push(row);
    });
    
    // We get the focused element (i.e. where the user wants to paste).
    let $focused = $('.is-focused');
    
    // We get metadata from the Interactive Grid.
    let rowId = $focused.closest('tr').data('id');
    let columnIndex = $focused.index();
    let headerIndex = $focused.closest('table').find('th').eq(columnIndex).data('idx');
    let ig$ = apex.region("EmployeesGrid").widget();
    let grid = ig$.interactiveGrid("getCurrentView");
    let model = grid.model;
    let columns = grid.getColumns();
    let record = model.getRecord(rowId);

    //Map visible columns
    let visibleColumns = columns.filter(function (val) { return !val.hidden; });
    visibleColumns.sort(function(a,b){return a.index - b.index;});

      // Complete the Promise after the grid is out of editing mode.
      rows.forEach(function(row) {
        row.forEach(function(value, offset) {
            if (record !== null) {
              visibleColumns.forEach(function(column, visColIdx) {
                if (visColIdx === (headerIndex + offset)) {
                  if (model.allowEdit(record)) {
                    model.setValue(record, column.property, Number(value));
                  }
                }
              });
            }
        });

        // To change record, get current record index and then get next record.
        let recordIndex = model.indexOf(record);
        record = model.recordAt(recordIndex + 1);
      });
  });
}
```

I have created a [sample application on apex.oracle.com](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/kyokohunter/r/interactive-grid-paste-from-excel/home) to demonstrate the behaviour, please note that I have set the grid to allow updates to existing rows only and that only the Sal and Comm number columns can be updated.

Comment: I think the problem is in getting the row, have you tried using model.getRecordId function? Can you give access to the workspace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a similar question raised on [Oracle Communities](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4479396/submitting-interactive-grid-column-session-state) where user Woodrow could visually see values that were automatically updated in an Interactive Grid column but those values weren't present when the page was submitted.

The answer they found was to set the value as a string:

```
model.setValue(record, column.property, value);
```

instead of a number:

```
model.setValue(record, column.property, Number(value));
```

This was necessary even if the column was declared as a 'Number' column in APEX.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use apex.locale JSAPI, is more APEX native way and won't cause issues in the future with APEX upgrades

```
var number = apex.locale.toNumber( "1,234.56" );
number = apex.locale.toNumber( "$1,234.56", "FML999G999G990D00" );
number = apex.locale.toNumber( "$1234.56", "FML999G999G990D00" );
```

Check this out
https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/21.2/aexjs/apex.locale.html#.toNumber

[image]

Comment: I found when using the `setValue` function of the `model` interface that the value had to be set as a string to work, although this isn't mentioned in Oracle's documentation at https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/21.2/aexjs/model.html#setValue. I also found apex.locale isn't in my version of APEX (19.2). I'll remember it to use when my APEX environment gets upgraded!